# Не розмовний варіант слова "підкаблучник"

Tags: синоніми

Цікавить чи можна вживати слово "підкаблучник" і, якщо ні, то чим його можна замінити?

В [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkabluchnyk) цього слова немає,але я знайшов його в Тлумачному словнику на сайті [E-slovnik](https://eslovnyk.com/%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> -а, ч., **розм.**, жарт. Про чоловіка, що знаходиться в повній підлеглості у дружини.

Чи є якісь інші варіанти (які можна зустріти в СУМі)? На жаль, мої пошуки в Інтернеті "синонімів до підкаблучника" більше нічого не дали.

Answer (score 4):

Сьогодні спеціально виділив свій вільний час для того, щоб все ж таки спробувати розібратися в цьому питанні.

Перш за все я вирішив порозпитувати у деяких викладачів свого університету. Одна викладачка сказала, що українською "подкаблучник" буде "підніжок". Варіант мені дуже сподобався, тому я вирішив подивитися чи він є в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidnizhok) і ось що там пише:

> ПІДНІ́ЖОК. жка, чол.
>
> **3. перен., зневажл. Той, хто плазує перед ким-небудь.** [Юрко:] Тепер ви бачите, який стоїть перед вами виродок, бузувір!.. Нікчемний підніжок,
>   негідний раб (Марко Кропивницький, III, 1959, 61); Він [О. Маковей]
>   таврував косність, боягузтво, всіх тих «духом бідних», що
>   перетворювалися у підніжків ворогів українського народу, хто інтереси
>   народу вимінював на власну вигоду і благополуччя (Жовтень, 2, 1956,
>   94).

Варіант цей мені подобається, хоч варто зазначити, що він не означає саме "чоловіка, що знаходиться в повній підлеглості у дружини".

Крім того, наткнувся на питання "Як українською слово "подкаблучник"?" на [Форумі Словника](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=1339), де, посилаючись на [Словник Виргана, Пилинської](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BA&scope=all&highlight=on), дають наступні варіанти:

> Быть под каблуком у кого (разг. фам.) – бути чиїм підніжком; бути
>   підніжком (за підніжок) у кого; бути під закаблуком (під ногами) в
>   кого; бути під пантофлею (під п’ятою) чиєю, у кого; жити за чиїм
>   загадом (розказом). [І старшина у нього під п’ятою і становий під
>   пахою!.. Кропивницький.]

Крім того, тут же бачимо Російсько-український словник складної лексики С. Караванський, 2012 (чернетка):

> КАБЛУ́К, под каблуко́м (у неї) під панто́флею, (не в неї) під п’ято́ю.

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pantofli):

> **ПАНТО́ФЛІ, фель і ів, мн. (одн. пантофля, і, жін. і пантофель, фля,
>   чол.). М'які кімнатні туфлі, звичайно без закаблуків.** Вона, вигідніше
>   сівши в невеличке кріселко і простягши свої маленькі ніжки, обуті в
>   шовкові пантофлі, прийняла журливо-поважний вид (Гнат Хоткевич, I,
>   1966, 51); Він хитнув ногою, і пантофля звалилася. Всі побачили голу
>   ніженьку, навіть без шкарпеток (Агатангел Кримський, Вибр., 1965,
>   346);

Ще цікаво, що німецькою підкаблучник буде "[Рantoffelheld](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pantoffelheld)". Гадаю, що можливо в українську мову вислів "бути під пантофлею" прийшов саме з німецької (хоч це лише моє припущення).

Отож, мені найбільше сподобався варіант "**бути підніжком**", але хочу зазначити, що можливі ще й:

**бути під закаблуком**

**бути під пантофлею** (приклади вживання у потрібному нам значенні - [1](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=VzU_AAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLgJDe56riAhWqAxAIHZMVA_MQ6AEIKTAA), [2](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=YHvnAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLgJDe56riAhWqAxAIHZMVA_MQ6AEILDAB))

**жити за чиїм загадом**